# Django 1.9 Type Error __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given - problems with class decorating

Tags: django, django-views

A bit of context: I'm trying to create a CreateView page for users to input information whilst working with Django 1.9 which is at URL '/profile/'.

When users are not logged in, and I go to the /profile/ url then it will redirect me to the login page as expected. However, when I am logged in to the site, and then go to /profile/ then it will display this error:

> TypeError at /profile/
>
> __ init __() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

At the moment, I'm decorating a class with a method_decorator, as mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class.

This is in my views.py:

```
    @login_required(login_url = "/login/", redirect_field_name = None)
    @method_decorator(login_required, name = 'dispatch')
    class SpkCreateView(CreateView):
        form_class = SpkCreateForm
        template_name = 'userprofile/spk_form.html'
        def get(self, request):
            form = self.form_class(None)
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
        def post(self, request):
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                spk_fname = form.cleaned_data['spk_fname']
                spk_lname = form.cleaned_data['spk_lname']
```

The 'name' argument for the method_decorator is also tripping me up so I'm not sure whether it's to do with that.

If anybody has any solutions then thanks!

Edit:

Changed `@login_required(login_url = "/login/", redirect_field_name = None)
        @method_decorator(login_required, name = 'dispatch')`

to `@method_decorator(login_required(login_url = "/login/", redirect_field_name = None), name = 'dispatch')`

and this is the traceback from Powershell

```
Internal Server Error: /profile/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[28/Sep/2016 22:20:22] "GET /profile/ HTTP/1.1" 500 57532
```

Answer (score 0):

You're decorating the class with `login_required` both with and without `@method_decorator`. You need to pass the decorator you want to use to `method_decorator`, in this case:

```
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url="/login/", redirect_field_name=None), name='dispatch')
class SpkCreateView(CreateView):
    ...
```

Comment: That still gives the same TypeError as before, unfortunately - thank you though. Have any other ideas what might be wrong or?

Comment: @jayt Please show your new attempt and the traceback.

Comment: I've made an edit in the question to show you what I did

Comment: @jayt Please show the complete traceback, not just the error message.